# Can the Ubuntu logo be used for a commercial website?

Tags: installation, logo, commercial, oem

Is there an Ubuntu logo that can be used on a commercial website to indicate that Ubuntu can be installed for customers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My reading of [the Ubuntu trademark policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy) is that any commercial use requires permission.

> **Restricted use that requires a trademark licence**
>
> Permission from us is necessary to use any of the Trademarks under any circumstances other than those specifically permitted above. These include:
>
> - Any commercial use. [OEM services](http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/oem-services/oem-services)
> - ...

That said, I imagine that you would get approved for such use. Use [this contact form](https://forms.canonical.com/trademark/) to  request an Ubuntu trademark license