# Can I use the Ubuntu logo on t-shirts produced non-comercially?

Tags: license, logo, policy, trademark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to create Ubuntu Shirts ( Merchandise )](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106735/is-it-possible-to-create-ubuntu-shirts-merchandise)

Is it permited to use(print) Ubuntu logo on a "Ubuntu users group" T-shirt which is not sold public but to the group members ?

(I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/58428/77519) question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage will be fine. Per the [Trademark & copyright policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy).

> Ubuntu is built by and largely for its community. We share access to
>   the Trademarks with the entire community for the purposes of
>   discussion, development and advocacy. We recognise that most of the
>   open source discussion and development areas are for non-commercial
>   purposes. We therefore allow the use of the Trademarks in this
>   context, provided the Trademark is used in a manner consistent with
>   the guidelines below:
>
> - there is no commercial intent behind the use
> - what you are referring to is in fact Ubuntu. If someone is confused into thinking that what isn't Ubuntu is in fact Ubuntu, you are
>     probably doing something wrong
> - there is no suggestion (through words or appearance) that your project is approved, sponsored, or affiliated with Ubuntu or its
>     related projects unless it actually has been approved by and is
>     accountable to the Ubuntu Community Council

Comment: this needs updating, I believe the wording has changed

Answer (score 1):

It's a big planet with a lot of different rules. You could probably do this legally in North Korea or a small Pacific island nation.

If you are in a country that observes and enforces international trade and copyright treaties, you need to read Canonical's [Trademark and Copyright policies page](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy). You can't use the Ubuntu name or logo without Canonical's permission for commercial use, according to the Community Advocacy paragraphs. Generally, this means that you can pass along the costs to produce the shirts, but you can't take a profit.

You should talk to a lawyer if you have a legal question. A cheaper alternative would be to just [contact Canonical](https://forms.canonical.com/trademark/) and ask. I've done it before and they were friendly and replied promptly. If your goal is to promote Ubuntu and just cover any costs, they can confirm that this is acceptable for you.

Answer (score -1):

*You can use the Ubuntu logo freely, as long as it isn't used to create a bad brand identity.*

Use the [Ubuntu Brand Guidelines](http://design.ubuntu.com/assets/ubuntu-logo) as a guide - though **make sure you don't misuse the logo** as pointed out in the 'Incorrect Use' section.

*Source: [Ubuntu Brand Guidelines](http://design.ubuntu.com/assets/ubuntu-logo).*